# Uninstall Ubuntu OS-Uninstaller

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 (I had the .iso already and couldnt be bothered downloading 14.04) alongside a broken Windows 7. GRUB shows Windows 7 and Ubuntu as normal

Before we go any further, I am not planning to uninstall Ubuntu in the near future. I just want to know how to do it just in case

I want to know if it's possible to uninstall Ubuntu using the OS-Uninstaller, while using Ubuntu to boot the uninstaller. Will it work, and, if so, what will I be left with?

Comment: well what if i run the os-uninstaller from a live ubuntu disc? and then uninstall it from there? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769489

Answer (score 0):

It will probably not work, especially if you launch it from within ubuntu.

Correct way to uninstall Ubuntu from a dual boot setup is explained in detail here: [How do I remove my Ubuntu partition from Windows 7 and reuse the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138250/how-do-i-remove-my-ubuntu-partition-from-windows-7-and-reuse-the-space)

To quote one of the answers:

```
You need to first fix your boot manager

boot your system using windows installation cd 
go to "repair your system" 
use command prompt 
type bootrec /fixboot then hit enter 
type bootrec /fixmbr then hit enter
exit

This time your system will boot directly into windows after doing this you can delete the partition as mentioned above.

This is the safe way to uninstall Ubuntu.
```