# How to remove Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

I just formatted the drive containing Ubuntu from Windows and merged the partition.

But when I go into the boot option, I can still see the Ubuntu option and GRUB is still there. Please tell me how to remove Ubuntu and GRUB completely...

Comment: Found this one [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138250/how-do-i-remove-my-ubuntu-partition-from-windows-7-and-reuse-the-space) on askubuntu.com ... Cheers, m8!

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: after this your disk is completely empty. All data gone.

You have to remove and recreate the partitions.
Start up with a live ubuntu cd/usb  and use fdisk to remove the partition(s).
When you install windows again the correct partitions wil be created.

When you only have one harddisk
1 boot ubuntu live cd
2 open a terminal
3 type: fdisk /dev/sda ( I assume you only have 1 disk)
type: d   (delete partition)
type enter
and repeat this until all partitions are gone.
4 Install Windows.

When you have more disk be very careful!
when you do: fdisk -l /dev/sda
you can see de configuration of the disk. Check if it is the right one.
when not type: fdisk -l /dev/sdb 
To see if this is the correct disk.

This is all your own risk. Be careful.