# How can I remove Ubuntu from a dual boot system?

Tags: dual-boot

I have two OSes installed, Ubuntu 14.10 and Windows 7. Now I want to remove Ubuntu from my system.

How can I remove Ubuntu and keep Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove my Ubuntu partition from Windows 7 and reuse the space?](https://askubuntu.com/q/138250/)

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Windows-question than Ubuntu, but the short answer is you boot into Windows. From there, start up [Disk Management](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-manage-your-disks-using-disk-management-utility). From there, just wipe your Ubuntu-partitions, and later resize your Windows-partitions over the free space you will gain.

Next, you need Windows to overwrite the boot, since you don't need GRUB anymore. [KB927392](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392) from Microsoft that might help, or the answers to [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader).