# delete Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, delete, boot-partition

I installed Ubuntu using ventoy on Windows.
In the setup screen, I clicked “Install Ubuntu” and “Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager”
I installed it on the C drive, not on a new partition.
Now i have no idea how to delete Ubuntu

Any solutions to delete Ubuntu?

Comment: You can [do this](https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/1222991) to restore your boot, then delete the Linux partitions in Windows with the Disk Manager tool.

Comment: You cannot install in the C: drive partition unless installing WSL inside Windows from Windows store. When you said along side the installer found a partition and made it smaller to have unallocated space for the Ubuntu install. While that usually works, better to use Windows tools to shrink a Windows NTFS partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove my Ubuntu partition from Windows 7 and reuse the space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138250/how-do-i-remove-my-ubuntu-partition-from-windows-7-and-reuse-the-space)